# Question regarding Fourier Transforms

Tags: signal-processing, fourier-transform

Still wrapping my head around FT.

How do you go about finding the Fourier Transform of the following function?

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{a^2 + t^2}$$

where $t$ is the time variable and $a$ is some constant.

Comment: Residue theorem can be handy.

Comment: Do you know the FT of $e^{-at}u(t)$, where $u(t)$ is a unit step function?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy the topic is to use the Fourier inversion theorem, not some contour integration

Comment: @msm yes, but I'm not sure how that can help this question yet.

Comment: OK I will give an answer in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

> $$\mathcal{F}(e^{-at}u(t))=\frac{1}{j\omega+a},\, a>0,$$

calculate the FT of $e^{-a|t|}$ using the properties of FT.

You can expand $e^{-a|t|}$ as follows:

$$e^{-a|t|}=e^{-at}u(t)+e^{at}u(-t)$$

After you did that, use the [duality property](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html) of the FT to find the answer to your question.